How to use lapply on strings so that they end up grouped together?
The actual issue: I'm trying to rearrange a bunch of names, street addresses, states, etc. into a nice list of addresses without any weird bracketed [row numbers], quotation marks, awkward breaks, etc.
So I've created 4 variables: address_name, address_line_1, address_line_2, address_line_3. I want those variables to go into a .txt document as
address_name
address_line_1
address_line_2
address_line_3

so that I've got a nicely-formatted list of addresses for my work.
Here is a simplified version of my code (using abc/123 instead of the actual variables):
letters <- c("a", "b", "c")
numbers <- c("1", "2", "3")

lapply(c(letters, numbers), function(c){ write(c, file = "Text_attempt.txt",  
                             sep = "\n", append = TRUE, 
                             ncolumns = 100000) })

It generates the following output:
a
b
c
1
2
3

But I want it to generate this output instead:
a
1
b
2
c
3


You don't really need an lapply here. You can create the vector and then write it out all in one go with
write(vctrs::vec_interleave(letters, numbers), file="Text_attempt.txt")

Other interleaving options here: How to merge 2 vectors alternating indexes?

You could try pasting them together before writing them:
letters <- c("a", "b", "c") numbers <- c("1", "2", "3")

lapply(paste(letters, numbers, sep = '\n'),
       function(c){ write(c, file = "Text_attempt.txt",
                          sep = "\n", append = TRUE, ncolumns = 100000) })


Thank you!! I really appreciate your help

We don't actually need lapply.  Replace stdout() with your file name.  No packages are used.
input <- c(letters[1:3], 1:3)

input |>
  matrix(nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE) |>
  c() |>
  write.table(stdout(), row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
## a
## 1
## b
## 2
## c
## 3


simply use rbind:
 cat(rbind(letters, numbers), sep="\n", file = "Text_attempt.txt")

or even paste:
cat(paste(letters, numbers, sep = '\n'), sep = '\n', file = "Text_attempt.txt")

